# GAE ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_mysql)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

My staging GAE app throws the below err,

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/foo156801/worker:20170301t222555.399535951340506041/lib/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
import _mysql
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (init_mysql)
```

which was exactly same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234503/google-appengine-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-function-init). According to the answer given on that link, I have changed my `app.yaml` MysqlDb version and the local mysqldb version to points to a same version. But no luck. Still I got the above error.

`app.yaml`

```
libraries:
 - name: jinja2
   version: latest
 - name: MySQLdb
   version: "1.2.5"
```

`requirements.txt`

```
Flask-API==0.6.9
MySQL-python==1.2.5
```

Comment: No, I made the requirements.txt file for to installing third party packages into `lib` folder. ie, `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`

Comment: Ah, I see, never mind :)

Comment: If I remove mysqldb package from my lib folder with the builtin mysqldb entry exists, it shows `No module named MySQLdb`. And if I remove the builtin entry and the mysqldb package still exists on my lib folder then it shows the above error.

Comment: @Dan But queries on default module works perfectly file.. But the db queries on worker module or service throws the above exception. I have `/api/users/list` endpoint on my default module which gets all the users from the database.. It works just fine..

Comment: But on the another api, I have set the default module to call a task which actually exists on worker module, say `/send-email` in worker.py . In this handler I added a query to search in one of my tables . This causes error.

Comment: 2 modules? You only show 1 `.yaml` file...

Comment: oh, wait.. I need to add mysqldb in worker module also (worker.yaml), right?.

Comment: finally it works......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple services/modules of an application do not share any code, see [Service isolation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine#service_isolation).

Because of this [requesting runtime-provided libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#requesting_a_library) or [vendoring in 3rd party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library) needs to be replicated in each service/module.

Symlinks can also be used for vendoring in 3rd party libs in DRY spirit, see [Sharing entities between App Engine modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291075/sharing-entities-between-app-engine-modules/34291789#34291789).

Comment: So it won't share also the environment variables? Like in the default module , i set `foo: bar` in app.yaml. Can I access that env variable in worker.py `os.environ.get('foo', 'None')`. Is this would return None?

Comment: Yep, `worker.yaml` needs its instructions as well. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307128/do-i-need-to-copy-skip-files-across-multiple-yaml-files/33308640#33308640

Comment: Fundamentally the modules are completely isolated from the code prospective, the worker module could be a flex env module, written in another language, with a totally different style of configurations.

Comment: ya, I already tested worker module completely written in php lang.